# ARM immediate value encoding and BIC instruction

Tags: assembly, arm, gnu

I am new to ARM world. In the **ARM Cortex-A series : Programmer's guide (page 71)**, there is an example for BIC instruction :

```
BIC R0, R0, #0x800
```

As per the text, this basically clears the bit 11 in R0. I understand that the BIC works like `R0 = R0 & (~val)` here (please correct me). But what I don't understand here is that how `#0x800` was taken as-is and gets translated to `1000 0000 0000` literally. Instead, it should have been split into 4-bit:8-bit part as per immediate encoding rules.

And as per my understanding of ARM encoding for constants:

```
0x800 = 0000 1000 0000 0000
```

Out of these bits, we consider only last 12 bits for encoding and out of these 12 bits - first 4 bits decide the right-rotation in steps of 2 and the last 8 bits is the number right-rotated (considering it as 32bit). So in this case, since last 8 bits are all zeros, I should have got `FFFF 0000` after 2*8 right-rotations.

And for the complete BIC instruction above, it should have then treated as :

```
R0 = R0 & (0000 FFFF)
```

I know I am wrong somewhere. Can someone please correct me.

Comment: @old_timer : Thanks for pointing out. I am only considering ARM for this quesiton. I will remove the thumb tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that you don't included an encoded literal field in your assembly, you include the value that has meaning, that you actually want to use. The assembler's job includes determining the (best, if there is one) instruction encoding for the specified assembly.

---

The assembler takes care of encoding values provided in assembly into the literal field of the instruction. `#0x800` is the literal. As an assembler programmer, you just need to ensure that the literal is encodable.

It would be annoying and incredibly error-prone to have to calculate encoded rotates. This type of conversion is much of the difference between assembly and machine code. To look at the actual generated literal field, look at the result after assembly.

This also leads to some of the non-1-to-1 relationship between assembly and machine code seen in some ISAs.

---

The value `0x800` is directly the `0b1000_0000_0000`.

Assembling

```
BIC R0, R0, #0x800
```

gives me

```
02 0B C0 E3
```

So the `Operand2` field is `0xB02`. This means that the Immediate is `0x02`, and the Rotate is `0xB`. Taking `0x00000002` and rotating right by `2 * 0xB`, we get the expected `0x800`.

Comment: Oh so does that mean the value we specify as the immediate value in the instruction is actualy the final required encodable value?

Comment: That's correct, programming in assembly you deal only with meaning, not actual instruction encoding. This is like how, in higher level languages, you deal with objects and functions, not the assembly that implements them.

Comment: @InsaneCoder I've added the assembly and analysis of the `Operand2` field.

Comment: @InsaneCoder The most common example of this is with the branch instruction.  You write `B label` not `B (label - .) / 4`  despite the later being how the destination address is encoded in the instruction.

Answer (score 2):

Just try it yourself and see.

```
.syntax unified

bic r0,r0,#0x800
.thumb
bic r0,r0,#0x800

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   e3c00b02    bic r0, r0, #2048   ; 0x800
   4:   f420 6000   bic.w   r0, r0, #2048   ; 0x800
```

A1 encoding

```
e3c00b02

101100000010 (b02)
1011 00000010
```

Shift the bit pattern 00000010 right 11*2 places which is the same as left 10

```
00000010 0000000000
000000100000000000
000000 1000 0000 0000
0x800
```

T1 encoding

```
f420 6000
1111010000100000 0110000000000000
xxxxx1xxxxxxxxxx x110xxxx00000000

11100 0000000
11100 abcdefg

1bcdefg0 shifted left 3

1abc defg 0000
1000 0000 0000 
0x800
```

All clearly described in the ARM documentation.  The instruction points to a part of the document (ARM ARM) that shows the encoding of the immediate bits.  This is not mips, this is ARM; it doesn't necessarily map directly into the instruction, ARM is/was known for their barrel shifter.

The one document (type) from ARM I avoid is the programmers guide, it is not one of their better documents.

You want the technical reference manual (ARM TRM) for the core in question and the architectural reference manual (ARM ARM) for the architecture in that core (armv7-ar in this case).

For ARM (aarch32 for lack of a better term these days) it is 8 significant bits that can be shifted an even number of times so

```
bic r0,r0,#0x102

100000010 (0x102)
10000001 (0x81)
```

won't work

```
so.s:2: Error: invalid constant (102) after fixup
```

but

```
bic r0,r0,#0x204
```

does (0x81 >> 30)

for thumb

```
bic r0,r0,#0x00220022
```

is perfectly fine, but not for arm

```
so.s:3: Error: invalid constant (220022) after fixup
```

Just read the ARM document, it is clearly described.